# I have deleted /etc/rc.d/ dirs, how can I restore them?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rm, undelete, rc.d

**I have accidentally deleted /etc/rc.d and /etc/rc0.d folders which resulted deletion of init.d and other related folders.**

1.What is the use of /etc/rc.d, rc, rc.d, rc0.d, rc1.d, rc2.d.......rc6.d and other files inside /etc/rc.d?

2.If we accidentally delete them how to recover?

3.If we have the same files in other server can we copy and get the situation to normal?

4.Suggest any possible way to minimize the impact or totally resolve this situation.

PLEASE HELPP!!!

**OS DETAILS here**

Linux version 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-027.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) SMP Wed Oct 26 10:25:23 EDT 2016

Comment: You should start by changing the root password and giving it only to those persons you can trust not to have accidents like that.  Only sure way to resolve is to restore these folders from your backup.

Comment: question 1. I don't know if EL6 uses systemd, if not, without the rc.d folders none of the services on your system will be started on reboot.  Before you reboot, make a list of all services running, so that you can reinstall them if necessary.

Comment: Check all plugins properly, you might have issues with them

Answer (score 2):

1. `/etc/rcX.d` (where X is the runlevel) contains symbolic (a.k.a. soft) links to init scripts in `/etc/init.d` that are to be executed by `/sbin/init` (on boot). It is explained for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 with pretty much detail here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/s2-boot-init-shutdown-init
2. The best thing would be to recover them from a recent backup (as already mentioned by Gerard H. Pille in his comment above). Should you lack such a backup you could try to recover them using `/sbin/chkconfig` or `/usr/sbin/ntsysv` which provides a ncurses user interface. I have no experience with it, but you can find a manual here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-services-ntsysv
3. If the other server has been set up in the exact same way (e.g. with ansible or some setup script) this might be a viable solution. In any case the structure of the other server could be helpful when using `/usr/sbin/ntsysv`
4. Try not to reboot the server until you have restored the `/etc/rc.d` folders and symlinks. Good luck!

According to the comment by Gerard below you could also try to install the yum-verify plugin:

```
yum install yum-plugin-verify
```

and make sure that you have

```
plugins=1
```

in `/etc/yum.conf`. Then execute

```
yum verify-all
```

and it should check all installed packages and report missing configuration files. Re-installing misconfigured packages should solve the problem, but again, I never had to do this myself.

**Update**
You should re-create the symbolic links for each and any service that is runninf on the identical other server with

```
chkconfig service_name on
```

where service_name is the name of the init.d script you want to start on boot. Using this command should make sure that the links are created within the appropriate runlevel folder.

You can check your progress with

```
chkconfig --list
```

and compare the output with the output on the other server.

You can find a chkconfig manual here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-services-chkconfig

Comment: Thanks @digijay Let me try this!

Comment: @TechUser You're running Enterprise Linux on multiple servers.  Can't you get assistance from someone with basic Linux knowledge?

Comment: Digijay, would yum allow him to check missing files for the installed packages?

Comment: Thanks Gerard, I've added this to my answer. BTW I have only limited knowledge of RH because I'm a Debian guy … and often RH/CentOS/Suse feels really annoying to me ;-) With Debian/ubuntu I would just use `rcconf` to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, digijay, Debian myself until I switched to Devuan.  Still, rcconf was new to me, knew it had to exist but never needed it.  And some extra knowledge about Redhat won't hurt.

Comment: Copied the files from another server (identical one) any idea or suggestions on restoring symlinks?? Please help with commands. Know that am bugging u all alot.. please help.

Comment: No problem, noone is being bugged :-) see my update above, hope it helps!