# does RedHat EL6 uses systemd?

Tags: linux, redhat, linux-kernel, rm, rc.d

Does EL6 uses systemd?

**OS DETAILS here**

Linux version 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-027.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) SMP Wed Oct 26 10:25:23 EDT 2016

Please answer with regard to [I have deleted /etc/rc.d/ dirs, how can I restore them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1013707/i-have-deleted-etc-rc-d-dirs-how-can-i-restore-them)

Answer (score 0):

Systemd only became the default init system with EL7.  According to your kernel, you have 6.8.  If your system uses systemd, it is because it was configured to do so, by default it would use Upstart.